# Linux - installing MySQL ODBC driver - error

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, debian, odbc

I'm trying to install **MySQL ODBC** driver to be able to connect to remote **MySQL** server from `python:3.9.5-slim-buster` docker.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out what to do. I just want to install MySQL ODBC drivers so I can connect using `DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Driver}`

1. Download https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/
2. The following this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-installation-binary-unix-tarball.html

I've add this to my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.9.5-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app


# build variables.
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# install Microsoft SQL Server requirements.
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl gcc g++ gnupg unixodbc-dev
# MYSQL
ADD https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-ODBC/8.0/mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.26-linux-glibc2.12-x86-64bit.tar.gz .
RUN tar -C . -xzvf mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.26-linux-glibc2.12-x86-64bit.tar.gz

RUN cp mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.26-linux-glibc2.12-x86-64bit/bin/* /usr/local/bin
RUN cp mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.26-linux-glibc2.12-x86-64bit/lib/* /usr/local/lib
RUN myodbc-installer -a -d -n "MySQL ODBC 8.0 Driver" -t "Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc8w.so"
```

This is the ERROR:

```
Step 9/14 : RUN cp mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.26-linux-glibc2.12-x86-64bit/lib/* /usr/local/lib
 ---> Running in 090acd838faa
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.26-linux-glibc2.12-x86-64bit/lib/plugin'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.26-linux-glibc2.12-x86-64bit/lib/private'
The command '/bin/sh -c cp mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.26-linux-glibc2.12-x86-64bit/lib/* /usr/local/lib' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Do you know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look for `lib` folder, you will see next:

```
cake@cake:~/tt/mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.26-linux-glibc2.12-x86-64bit/lib$ ls -alh
total 53M
drwxr-xr-x 4 cake cake 4.0K 6月  27 21:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 cake cake 4.0K 7月  31 12:59 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cake cake  27M 6月  27 21:52 libmyodbc8a.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cake cake  27M 6月  27 21:52 libmyodbc8w.so
drwxr-xr-x 2 cake cake 4.0K 6月  27 21:52 plugin
drwxr-xr-x 3 cake cake 4.0K 6月  27 21:52 private
```

You could see you have folder `plugin` & `private` in `lib`. Check the usage of `cp` you could see next:

> ```
>    -R, -r, --recursive
>          copy directories recursively
> ```

This means when copy things with folder, you will have to add `-r`. So, for your scenario, you need change to next to make you work:

```
RUN cp -r mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.26-linux-glibc2.12-x86-64bit/lib/* /usr/local/lib
```